# good resources for getting started with algorithms

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, learning

I am reasonably mathematically competent and use algorithms regularly in computing, however I have started reading through 'introduction to algorithms' but find I need to understand a few more basics of algorithms (mathematical symbols, summations etc.) in equations to get maximum out of it.

Can someone suggest resources which might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a gentle introduction, I suggest the Oreilly book [Algorithms in a Nutshell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059651624X) As with most other "nutshell" books, the contents are well organized and it is very readable.

Now, if you want to get more theoretical and in-depth, its hard to find a modern treatise that is more thorough than [Introduction to Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844) by Cormen, et. al.

Comment: That's the book I have been working with however there is a little too much assumed knowledge for me and not enough walk through of the exercises so I am looking for a jump start, is o'reilly the same level

Comment: @whatsthebeef No, The Orielly book is a much easier read and has a really nice selection of algorithms and examples. Browse it on Amazon and see what you think.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the (student run!) course *Algorithms* at the University of Cambridge. The course website is [here](http://www.srcf.ucam.org/algorithms/). The course is pitched to be understandable by first year undergraduates, and the website includes full lecture notes, video lectures and homework.

Comment: Will check it out, hope there are plenty of worked examples

Answer (score 2):

Who is the author of your book "Introduction to algorithms"? Because i read years ago very simple books about algorithms, but anyway the course suggested by Chris Taylor is a good starting point.

Comment: Thomas Cormen (the author mentioned by 3Sphere) it's got some great content but there is a little too much assumed knowledge for me and not enough walk through of the exercises

Answer (score 2):

[The Algorithm Design Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849967202) by Skiena is a more advanced book than *Introduction to Algorithms*, but it does a good job of laying down the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

If you like Python, (a very nice language that lets you do stuff quickly), [this python-based algorithm book](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_67?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=python%20algorithms%20mastering%20basic%20algorithms%20in%20the%20python%20language&x=0&y=0&sprefix=python%20algorithms%20mastering%20basic%20algorithms%20in%20the%20python%20language) is a nice choice.